# Configure Apple login in Djangowith and Allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, apple-sign-in

I am using Django and REST framework and I want to setup Apple Sign-in on my web application. I have installed the libraries and all the other necessary details on the apple developer console.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "apple": {
        "APP": {
            # Your service identifier.
            "client_id": "your.service.id",

            # The Key ID (visible in the "View Key Details" page).
            "secret": "KEYID",

             # Member ID/App ID Prefix -- you can find it below your name
             # at the top right corner of the page, or it’s your App ID
             # Prefix in your App ID.
            "key": "MEMAPPIDPREFIX",

            # The certificate you downloaded when generating the key.
            "certificate_key": f.read() #reading the key from a file
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added a URL pattern as path('accounts', include('allauth.urls'))
Now how to do proceed further, I added the domain and redirect URL of my platform
lets say https://abcdef.com/, and when I moved to https://abcdef.com/accounts/apple/login, I got invalid request and invalid callback URL.

Also what is the purpose of callback URL? and how to setup the endpoints which will handle the authentication and what code to write there or do I need to add some sort of entries in the alluth model, when I migrate it ?

Please help if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

[djago-allauth docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/providers.html#apple) about Apple login provider has as callback example:

`http://example.com/accounts/apple/login/callback/`. Notice the difference with your current URL:
`http://example.com/accounts/apple/login`.

Also from the docs, "Apple uses a slight variation of OAuth2" meaning the callback is meant to handle the authorization code grant in the OAuth2 workflow ([see workflow](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/authorization-code-flow#how-authorization-code-flow-works))